# Using Custom Tool and C/C++ in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to create two different configurations for my VS2010 C-library project: one configuration is "regular" C/C++, the other one uses a custom compiler.

Unfortunately, when I create the two configurations for the project I'm either able to specify "C/C++" configuration properties for both configurations or "Custom Build Tool" for both configurations, but not "C/C++" for one and "Custom" for the other.

Same happens on the "item" (C-file) level.

To work around that problem I've created two mutually exclusive projects, but that is ugly  - e.g. when adding files or modifying common properties one has to do it in two places instead of one, etc.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very unclear.  Use the Visual C++, General, Makefile Project template for the "custom compiler" project.  You get to write the specific commands you need for the Build, Rebuild and Clean operations and set the debugger start command.  The odds that you get both projects to have *anything* in common are of course -42%.

Comment: @HansPassant, actually, they have almost everything in common - including the linker invocation. The only thing that is different is the compiler command line.

Please tell me what's unclear to you and I'll reword the question.